# Searching / Indexing huge file amounts

Tags: java, filesystems, io

I'm struggeling to find an efficient way (< 0.5 sek) to search for specific files in a huge file system having only a little part of the desired file name.

Here's the scenario:

Consider you have about 15.000.000 files all categorised by their type of information contained an batched within numbered directories containing 20.000 files each:

```
DATA
--TYPE_1_001
----ID_1234567_TYPE1.XML
----ID_2345678_TYPE1.XML
----[...]
--TYPE1_002
--[...]
--TYPE_1_097
--TYPE_2_001
----ID_1234567_TYPE2.JPG
----ID_2345678_TYPE2.JPG
----ID_2345679_TYPE2.JPG
----[...]
--[...]
--TYPE2_304
--[...]
```

and so on.

So, given the ID (i.e. 1234567), I'm trying to find all relevant filenames containing said id.
This "find process" will be executed for each of the 7.000.000 ids given in another XML file.

The current process would take 405 days to process all 7.000.000 ids, which - who figures - is inacceptable ;)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any way you can extract the data into a database or index (such as Lucene) of some description?

That would take some time to do but would be much faster to search once it was available.

Comment: I was in fact thinking about extracting ALL path information via a simple `find -name` command and putting it into a database, using the contained id as the key. Problem is that there would be around 21.000.000 documents in the database which might not perform either. But I will look into that.

Comment: A database or index should perform much better, if configured properly, than a filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Using an SSD drive instead of a hard drive.  A regular hardware can only perform around 120 IOs per second. This is because the head has to move to the location where the information is stored.  A fast SSD drive cna perform 10,000 IO operations per second as there is no moving parts. However even with an SSD drive it going to take you about 2 seconds at best to scan the names of every directory.

If you want it to be faster than that you need to cache/index the names and look them up from memory.

BTW: If you had a SSD Raid 6 set, it could perform IO fast enough to scan 20K files in under 0.5 seconds.

Comment: We're trying some workaraound using a tmpfs right now, which has the same advantages. But it is still a workaround. And using an SSD of this size is too expensive for a "simple" proof of concept (although I'm aware that this amount of data is no POC anymore, but hey: customer is king - as we say in germany ;) ).

Comment: You can buy a 60 GB SSD with a max seek time of 0.1 ms for less than £80 in the UK. Trying to achieve the same performance improvement using software is not so simple.